# perl: search & replace by grouping

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to update version in  assemblyinfo file using perl command line (`perl -i.bak -ape`), I was thinking (obviously wrong) that `s/\d+\.\d+\.(\d+).(\d+)/5.1/`  would just replace the grouped, but actually it replaces entire version. here is what i need.

```
OLD=1.0.0.0
NEW=1.0.5.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\K` to cut away the part you don't want to replace (keep everything till `\K`). Like so:

```
s/\d+\.\d+\.\K\d+\.\d+/5.1/
```

If your Perl version does not support `\K` (old), you could use a capturing group like:

```
s/(\d+\.\d+)\.\d+\.\d+/$1.5.1/
```

Also escaped the `.` for you, if you don't a `.` matches any character (except a new line without `/s`).

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to update a specific version, consider matching that version and use a positive lookbehind to keep the part you don't want to change:

```
s/(?<=1\.0\.)0\.0/5.1/
```

Hope this helps!